# SCSS 'partially compiled', variables left in CSS?

Tags: sass

I have no background in SCSS, but I want to make a small change to an existing SCSS and recompile it. However, I found that variables with a dollar sign appear in the output CSS. Even if I discard my changes, the output CSS does not match the original.

For example,

```
@-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {...
```

is in my output, while

```
@-webkit-keyframes move-up {...
```

is the expected original output.

I think it is either because I didn't use the right command to compile the SCSS files, or because the SCSS files were written for an older compiler.

I have tried the following commands (I clear any output before each trial):

```
sass --scss main.scss main.css
sass --scss --update main.scss:main.css
sass --scss --update .
```

Because main.scss imports another SCSS file, I also tried copying the content of the depedent SCSS file into main.scss. This didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason variable names are printed instead of their values is because they were not **interpolated** so sass uses them as the values instead.

You should write

```
//Assuming a variable $animation-name: move-up;
@-webkit-keyframes #{$animation-name} { ....
```

Which gets compiled to

```
@-webkit-keyframes move-up { ....
```

Without the interpolation sass believes that the `$animation-name` is the *actual name* intended to be used as the name for the animation.

Comment: This works; thank you! I still wonder how the original author of this piece of SCSS managed to compile -- is there a compiler that doesn't require interpolation?

Comment: It's not an error so it will compile. It's just that the lines of code have different meanings to sass. When the variable is interpolated, `#{$animation-name}` you're telling sass to use the value stored in that variable instead whereas without interpolation, `$animation-name` sass just uses the text as is. However if a variable name is supplied where CSS expects a _value_, it doesn't require interpolation. `selector { color: $color_value }`